# Nielsen & Chuang Exercise 2.2 - Matrix representations in different input and output basis

Tags: mathematics, matrix-representation, nielsen-and-chuang

This is a question in the Nielsen and Chuang textbook (Exercise 2.2).

> Suppose $V$ is a vector space with basis $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$
>    and $A$ is a linear operator from $V \to V$ such that $A|0\rangle =
>  |1\rangle$ and $A|1\rangle =|0\rangle$. Given a matrix representation
>    for $A$, with respect to the input basis $\{|0\rangle, |1\rangle\}$
>    and output basis $\{|1\rangle,  |0\rangle\}$. Find input and output
>    basis which give rise to a different matrix representation of A.

My doubts:

1. Why do we mention the input and output specifically? Isn't the matrix-dependent only on the input and output as long as the transformation is in the same vector space?
2. How to solve the second part of the question?

Comment: **Related:** [Nielsen & Chuang Exercise 2.2 - “Matrix representations: example”](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2423)

Comment: "*Why do we mention the input and output specifically? Isn't the matrix-dependent only on the input and output as long as the transformation is in the same vector space?*" I don't understand, aren't you answering yourself? The matrix representation depends on input/output bases, and the question is asking to verify this by computing the matrix representation in a different input/output basis

Comment: also, does the linked post answer your question? If not, could you specify what in the answer there you find unclear?

Comment: Yes thank you it did, sorry I did not see the message