# In the solution of exercise 2.2(on this site) how can we see the new form of the operator A, in the beginning of the answer.?

Tags: quantum-gate, textbook-and-exercises

[this is the question I am referring to](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2423/nielsen-chuang-exercise-2-2-matrix-representations-example/2424#2424?newreg=ce160fc1541f418a943fd05b6cf1e5b9)

I am sorry to ask such a question, can someone explain how are we able to make the new form of the operator A.

Thank you, any help would be great!

Comment: What do you mean by the new form? Do you mean the second example they provided in which they has a different input and output basis?

Comment: In the beginning the answer starts with a result, equating the operator A to sum of outer product of basis states, i don't understand how that happened!

Comment: Yeah I just assumed that was what you meant. Did my answer explain things?

Comment: I might be wrong, but stating that result is essentially the answer what remains is just tensor or matrix matrix multiplication. Can you explain that in baby steps? :)  Thank you!

Comment: The matrix multiplication or the actioj of A? I'm not sure what part my answer didn't cover.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how does the answer immediately state that $A=|1\rangle \langle 0|+|0\rangle \langle 1|$, the reason is because in the question, it tells us that $A|0\rangle = |1\rangle$ and $A|1\rangle = |0\rangle$

So we can see that we need two operators that perform these mappings:

$|1\rangle \langle 0|0\rangle = |1\rangle$ and $|0\rangle \langle 1|1\rangle=|0\rangle$

A far easier way, however, is simply taking what we know about the behaviour of A, and using the Identity operator along with the inner product function:

$$IAI=\sum_{i}|i\rangle \langle i|A\sum_{j}|j\rangle \langle j|=\sum_{i,j}|i\rangle \langle j|\langle i|A|j\rangle$$

This way, you can calculate the entries of A based on it's actions on the input and output states, along with the associated operator.